# Get error when using custom exception in python

Tags: python, mongodb

i have custom exception for inserting data:

```
class ErrorOnInsert(BaseException):
    """Exception raised for errors in insert data to db

    Attributes:
        resource -- resource name
        message -- explanation of the error
    """

    def __init__(self, resource: str):
        self.message = 'Failed to insert data for {}!'.format(resource)
        super().__init__(self.message)
```

exception is used in this insert function to mongo:

```
def _add(self, data: RunnerRating):
        try:
            dict_data = data.as_dict()

            self.collection[self.document_name].insert_one(
                        dict_data)
            self.list_data.add(data)
        except ErrorOnInsert(self.document_name) as e:
            raise e
```

and i try to test the exception with `self.repo._add(None)` but it shows error something like this:

> FAILED tests/integration/test_repo.py::RatingRepoTest::test_add -
> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is
> not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks like it's a catch with a pattern match (which isn't a thing in Python).

Are you maybe looking for

```
def _add(self, data: RunnerRating):
    try:
        dict_data = data.as_dict()
        self.collection[self.document_name].insert_one(dict_data)
        self.list_data.add(data)
    except Exception as e:
        raise ErrorOnInsert(self.document_name) from e
```